# Yank text between certain words or marks

Tags: vim

Is there some vim-magic to yank between two strings?

As example:

```
#%%
some example
or

some other

#%%
```

I would like to yank everthing in between (#%%)? Like the "yi(" command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`y` works with all motions, which includes `/`.

`/#%%` and then `wyn` would accomplish what you want, where

- `/#%%`: search for the literal symbols `#%%`. As long as your cursor was above the section you want to yank, this will highlight the first instance.
- `wyn`: move one `w`ord forward, to not include `#%%` in your yank (this assumes `#%%` is space separated from everything you want to yank). `yn` just means "`y`ank all text until the `n`ext instance of the search".

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t care that `:yank` is linewise, you could do

```
:/#%%/+,/#%%/- yank
```

Since patterns count as addresses, we can write a range that selects the inner text, and then yank it.